# Is there a way to share a document in Workdocs via the Workdocs API?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-workdocs

as far as i know i can share or download a document in Workdocs via the Amazon Workdocs UI. I am trying to build a static website in a S3 bucket that offers a Link to a Workdoc document for download.

Thus i have to share this document after verifying some stuff.
Sadly i found nothing similiar in the API documentation (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/workdocs/latest/APIReference/workdocs-api.pdf).

NodeJs would be fine using JDK but i can also try to use lambda functions if necessary.

Greetings,

Eric

Answer (score 1):

You can build AWS python3+ based AWS Lambda along with AWS Step Functions.

```
import boto3

work_docs_client = boto3.client('workdocs')  # Change aws connection parameters as per your setup


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # Call share_document_work_docs(resource_id, recipient_id) based on your conditions/checks
    return None  # change this as per your use-case


# This will add the permissions to the document to share
def share_document_work_docs(resource_id, recipient_id):
    principals = [{'Id': recipient_id, 'Type': 'USER', 'Role': 'VIEWER'}]  # change this as per your use-case

    share_doc_response = work_docs_client.add_resource_permissions(

        ResourceId=resource_id,
        Principals=principals,
        NotificationOptions={
            'SendEmail': True,
            'EmailMessage': 'Your message here',
        }  # change NotificationOptions as per your use-case
    )

    return share_doc_response
```

Comment: i kind of understand your answer i guess. i tried this with an AuthenticationToken and i get a 200 response. i dont quite understand two things though:
- how can i read the share_doc_response?
- if i understand this right, this will share the document with a specific user, but i want to share it with a person that is unauthenticated.

Comment: @w-eric - 1) `share_doc_response` is of type Python Dictionary (a.k.a. `dict`). So you can refer [this add_resource_permissions](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/workdocs.html#WorkDocs.Client.add_resource_permissions) API response syntax. I would suggest to `print (share_doc_response)` just to view the api response structure in your example. Regarding how to read from `share_doc_response` `dict`, you can refer [this](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp) python document about `dict`.

Comment: @w-eric -  2) Regarding,  share it with a person that is unauthenticated. You can refer boto3 API document as well as [aws cli example inputs only](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/workdocs/add-resource-permissions.html) provided for `anonymous` access. You can pass same inputs for this case.